# Reactjs and Firebase - Adding object to users in db and generating unique URL for that object

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm wanting to be able to click a button "new" then call a function in my db.js file (similarly to how I create new users) that creates a new EventPage.

Each user has their own list of EventPages they've created, and inside that EventPage there should be attributes like Name, EventCode etc.

I would like to somehow then let ANYONE for example go to the URL.com/Events/EventCode19xiu and it to bring up that EventCode19xiu page that was generated by some user.

So 1. **How do I create a list of events in my db under users.**

And 2. **How do I create the event that will be a page accessible through its own unique URL?**

*I'm really new to firebase and react and if you could point me in the right direction that'd be great (especially a tutorial doing similar things)!*

---

Here's my db.js file (I've already got it all setup with firebase authentication/users):

```
import { db } from './firebase';

// User API

export const doCreateUser = (id, username, email) =>
  db.ref(`users/${id}`).set({
    username,
    email,
  });

export const onceGetUsers = () =>
  db.ref('users').once('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save to DB is a **State** like this.

```
User 1: {
    username: 'User1',
    email: 'testuser1@testsmtp.com',
    events:[
            eventPage1: {
            Name: 'Event1',
            EventCode: '001'
            },
            eventPage2: {
            Name: 'Event2',
            EventCode: '002'
            }
    ]
}
User 2: {
    username:'User2',
    email:'testuser2@testsmtp.com',
    events:[
            eventPage1: {
            Name: 'Event1',
            EventCode: '003'
            }
    ]
}
```

I this case you should be constructing your user object like this and saving it to the firebase, later which you can fetch the same.

Coming to the unique URL part, what I could understand from **unique URL** is you are trying to do something like **URL.com/Events/EventCode19xiu** , you can do that using 
[React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

In React-Router you can using **LINK** to achieve this.

```
<Link 
  key={id} 
  to={{
    pathname: this.props.match.url + '/' + foo,
    search: '?EventCode=' + eventCode
  }} />
```

The search parameters can later be accessed via new **URLSearchParams()** like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
        console.log(param);
    }
}
```

Certainly there are other ways in React-Router to do the same , please check [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy)

Hope this helps !

Comment: How do I add that to the firebase? Firebase states I cannot edit the User object, but I can add additional details in the real-time database, but how?

So I want Users, then I want to be able to get a User's Events (which will have objects/lists of its own)

Comment: You mean you are facing difficulty in editing users in FireBase am I right?